# Are junction / join tables always necessary

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-theory

I have tried looking across other answers for this, so far I have not quite found what I am after. While there are multiple questions regarding junction tables, none seem to address whether a junction table is necessary to have between a table and 2 other tables which have a Many-to-Many relationship or why it is necessary.

As an example I have a database to store path normalisation data for a system. There are multiple paths in the system and there are multiple runs of normalisation over time.

So a specific `Normalisation Run` is normalising multiple different `Paths`, and a specific `Path` is normalised over multiple `Normalisation Runs`. A Many-to-Many relationship between `Normalisation Runs` and `Paths`.

The `Normalisation Data` needs to refer to a specific `Normalisation Run`, however multiple `Normalisation Data` records can be associated to a single `Normalisation Run`, so a One-to-Many relationship.

The `Normalisation Data` needs to also refer to a specific `Path`, however multiple `Normalisation Data` records can be associated to a single `Path`, so again a One-to-Many relationship

Also to clarify 2 different `Normalisation Data` records may refer to the same (`Normalisation Run-Path`) pair

Which of the following is the best design for the database?

**Option 1: With a junction table**

[image: normalisation database design with junction table]

(or)

**Option 2: Without a junction table**

[image: normalisation database design without junction table]

Here is an example of the `Normalisation Data` table:

| Norm_Data_ID | Norm_Run_ID | Path_ID | Freq_MHz | Path_Loss_dB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 100 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 120 | 0.6 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 200 | 1.2 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | 240 | 1.6 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 | 100 | 0.7 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 | 120 | 0.8 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 | 200 | 1.0 |
| 8 | 2 | 2 | 240 | 1.4 |

Is the `Path Runs` junction table really necessary in this situation, as `Normalisation Data` table will still contain exactly the same data without it. If it is necessary what are the reasons why this is necessary?

Comment: Are `Paths` dependent on `Normalisation_Runs`, or are any combinations of `(Norm_Run_ID, Path_ID)` valid?  If the former, your first model is correct.  If the latter, the second.

Comment: *The Normalisation Data needs to refer to a specific Normalisation Run and a specific Path* If 2 different NormalisationData may refer to the same (NormalisationRun-Path) pair then 1st scheme is correct else 2nd one.

Comment: @Akina 2 different NormalisationData may refer to the same (NormalisationRun-Path) pair, I have updated the question to clarify that. However regardless of the ```Path Runs``` being there or not, ```Normalisation Data``` would still contain the exact same data, so would you be able to tell me why the 1st scheme would be correct?

Comment: I see columns in `Normalisation Data` which are non-related to the relations. So I cannot understand why you tell about *the exact same data*...

Comment: Those columns which are non-related to the relations can have multiple different values which are repeated over the same (Normalisation Run-Path) pair

Comment: Time to read a textbook on information modelling & DB design. (Manuals for tools for recording & using models & designs are not such textbooks.)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a bridhge table.

as you wrote

> The Normalisation Data needs to refer to a specific Normalisation Run and a specific Path

so you have a 1:1 relationship between Normalisation Data and  Normalisation Run
And you have a 1:1 relationship between Normalisation Data and  Path

only when have m:n relationship between Normalisation Data and the other two  you need one.

Comment: Apologies if my question was a little unclear earlier, I have tried to clarify it a bit further. There is 1:n relationship between ```Normalisation Runs``` and ```Normalisation Data``` and likewise there is 1:n relationship between ```Normalisation Runs``` and ```Paths```. Also to clarify 2 different ```Normalisation Data``` records may refer to the same (Normalisation Run-Path) pair

Comment: as is aid in my answer that doesn't matter, as both Normalisation Data can save the same  (Normalisation Run-Path) pair, a Problem that has to be adressed with bridge tables is when **one** Normalisation Data has two or more (Normalisation Run-Path) pairs. You see it is thwe other way around, when you need a bridge table

Comment: I am a little unclear about your comment _a Problem that has to be adressed with bridge tables is when one Normalisation Data has two or more (Normalisation Run-Path) pairs_ - wouldn't that require another bridge table between ```Path Runs``` and ```Normalisation Data```

Comment: your table shows clearly that **every** Normalisation Data needs **one** Normalisation Run and **one** Path, this means this it **not** a n:m Relationship it is a 1:1 between all thre tables, in an EER you display this an 1 on Normalisation Data and a infinity in for example Path. I accept that that is really confusing. but  so are the rules, normalization means that you remove redundant informationand replaced it with integer, which onply need 1-8 Bytes for every entry(you can also your uuids which needs 16

Comment: (Normalisation Run-Path) pair is repeated multiple times in the ```Normalisation Data``` table for different ```Freq_MHz``` and ```Path_Loss_dB``` values so based on my understanding that ```Path_Runs``` has a 1:n relationship with ```Normalisation Data```

Answer (score 0):

You have a many:to:many relationship between Norm_Runs and Paths, correct?  Hence `Normalisation Data` (in option 2) is the necessary bridge table.like

Optionally, you could get rid of the table `Paths` and simply have the `Path` spelled out in `Normalisation Data`.  If there are really more columns in `Paths`, this suggestion should be ignored.

I think the notation in Option 1 is wrong, hence confusing.  It seems like `Path Runs` and `Normalization Data` would be 1:1.  At that point, follow this general rule:  Never have two tables in 1:1 relationship; combine them.  (There are exceptions, and some cases where splitting should happen for performance.)

Comment: ```Path Runs``` and ```Normalisation Data``` are not 1:1 as you can see from the ```Normalisation Data``` table where the (```Norm_Run_ID```-```Path_ID```) pair is repeated for multiple ```Freq_MHz``` and ```Path_Loss_dB``` values, so it should be a 1:n relationship according to me